# Refreshing $scope from provider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, server-sent-events

We are working on an Angularjs provider for our API. Our API offers the ability to use Server Sent Events to receive messages from our servers on the client side. Unfortunately, AngularJS does not have builtin provider for EventSource, like it has for $http or $timeout.

Here's what we have so far:

```
var ngSuperfeedr = angular.module('ngSuperfeedr', []);

// The superfeedr client!
function SuperfeedrClient(http, config) {
  this.http = http;
  this.config = config;
}

// Stream method which connects to Eventsource
SuperfeedrClient.prototype.stream = function stream(url, options, callback) {
  if(!options) {
    options = {};
  }
  if(!options.format) {
    options.format = "json";
  }
  options['hub.mode'] = 'retrieve';
  options['hub.topic'] = url;
  options['authorization'] = Base64.encode([this.config.login, this.config.token].join(':'));

  var source = new EventSource(buildUrl(options, 'https://stream.superfeedr.com/?'));
  source.addEventListener("notification", function(e) {
    // Do stuff which will also update the scope!
    callback(e);
  });
};

ngSuperfeedr.provider('Superfeedr', function() {

  var config = {};

  this.configure = function(_config) {
    config = _config;
    return config;
  }

  this.$get = ["$scope", function Superfeedr($http) {
    return new SuperfeedrClient($http, config)
  }];
});
```

So far, so good. On the end, implementers are able to do something like:

```
...
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, Superfeedr) {
  $scope.count = 0;

  $scope.stream = function stream() {
    Superfeedr.stream($scope.item.subscription.feed.url, {}, function(error, result) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.count += 1;
      });
    });
  }
});
...
```

The problem is that I'd love to handle the `$scope.$apply` stuff inside the provider because I'm sure we'll end up having a lot of problems because people will forget to include it in their controllers.

So, I tried to *expose* the `$scope` in our provider, but we get an error because $scope is only available to controllers and directives. How to solve this connendrum?

Comment: I believe you can use `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`. Have you tried that?

Comment: you can always use $broadcast to send events and update scope where you want...